# Upper & Underline text with variable number of lines

Tags: html, css, formatting

I need to work with documents templates on site and have problem with preparing templates with complex formatting of such type:

```
No underline here:  TEXT UPPER TEXT UPPER TEXT UPPER TEXT UPPER 
                    -------------------------------------------
                     descriptive subtext descriptive subtext

CONTINUE UPPER TEXT UPPER TEXT UPPER TEXT UPPER TEXT UPPER 
------------------------------------------------------------
continue subtext descriptive subtext descriptive subtext
```

So that upper text is text I will add into template from forms, and subtext is text is descriptive comment. ***Problem is that length of lines of both texts are variable*** and can't be known for sure before filling and often inserted text is in more than one string.

Such variant works well for upper text and underline it, but I don't see how to add sub-text there...

```
<span>This is intro text without underline: </span><span style='border-bottom: 1px solid black; line-height: 50px;'>Nunc venenatis nibh nec odio gravida, ac ultricies lectus sagittis. Nam magna lorem, sagittis sed dignissim at, luctus eu magna.Nunc venenatis nibh nec odio gravida, ac ultricies lectus sagittis. Nam magna lorem, sagittis sed dignissim at, luctus eu magna.Nunc venenatis nibh nec odio gravida, ac ultricies lectus sagittis.</span>
```

[JSFiddle examle](http://jsfiddle.net/a0jofb0z/)

Comment: If you want a robust solution you're going to have to use JavaScript to measure string length, then create and absolutely position the spans below your underline text.

Comment: I don't mind using JavaScript, but better if it will be some clear solution without mess of code. One more problem - the HTML will be later converted to PDF and multi-page documents are also an issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**if you had short lines:**

Can you use description lists?  Set up the list like:

```
<dl>
  <dt>Coffee</dt>
    <dd>black hot drink</dd>
  <dt>Milk</dt>
    <dd>white cold drink</dd>
</dl>
```

and style with CSS.

```
dt {
     text-decoration: underline;
     text-transform: uppercase;
}

dd {
    margin-left:0;
}
```

see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/colost8rams/55fvx2cm/)

**For longer lines:**

you could use absolute positioning of `div`s combined with line heights of 2. you basically set the line spacing of both divs at 2 and then position the lower div `1em` below the top one.  HTML code would be like:

```
<div class="topline">TEXT UPPER TEXT UPPER TEXT UPPER TEXT UPPER</div>
<div class="bottomline">descriptive subtext descriptive subtext</div>
```

and then the CSS:

```
.topline {
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 2;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}

.bottomline {
    margin-left:0;
    line-height: 2;
    position:absolute;
    top:1em;
    left:0;
}
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/colost8rams/55fvx2cm/1/).

Comment: This doesn't work for multiple lines! http://jsfiddle.net/fj8jc1a6/ - see here how it looks on big text

Comment: Yes, the second JsFiddle is what I need! Thank you very much! I had thought about something such, but wasn't sure how to set correct properties for CSS, now I see the solution! Please add code from your solution to your unswer for more easy search in future and I will accept it.

Comment: The one thing I did not consider was, do the letters on the bottom row have to line up with the letters on top?

Comment: edited my answer to include the code example for the second of my 2 options.